# Encrypt Cookie in browser

Tags: javascript, security, browser, cookies, encryption

I want to encrypt cookie in browser

Please tell me the different ways to do this

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by encrypt in browser?

Comment: With JavaScript, you cannot encrypt in such a way that it's safe. One could always track the source code to decrypt it as well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your question isn't very clear. You should use HTTPS for the connection and set the secure flag to make sure that the cookie is always sent encrypted. I assume that is what you want to do.

If you're thinking about doing your own encryption in JavaScript then don't do it because you won't get the level of neither security nor performance anywhere near that of SSL/TLS that the browser has already built in.

If you're serious about cookies security then I recommend reading the Secure Cookie Protocol paper by Liu, Kovacs, Huang and Gouda ([PDF](http://www.cse.msu.edu/~alexliu/publications/Cookie/cookie.pdf)).

Answer (score 1):

You never encrypt cookies. If you have to then your security model is flawed. You should tell more about the problem you are trying to solve for us to help you better.

EDIT: Why the downvote? Explain when you disagree.

Comment: It's not my down vote, but can understand the -1. Your statement is overly broad.  There are many reasons you may want to encrypt a cookie.  True, you can put silly things in a cookie that should not be there.  Simply wanting to encrypt the cookie in no way makes your security model flawed.

Comment: Also, others have no obligation to explain why they disagree with your post, although it is courteous.  Asking more politely will increase the chance of a response from the voter.